# Faster multiple matrix value assignments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to calculate the `norm` of each column of a large matrix (tens rows with thousands of columns) containing `NaN`. Prior to calculating the `norm`, each column is subtracted by its mean. All `NaN` values are treated as 0. Thus I perform these as

```
nanix = isnan(X);
nx = sum(~nanix); % count the number of non-NaN values in each column for calculating mean
X(nanix) = 0;
X = bsxfun(@minus, X, sum(X)./nx);
X(nanix) = 0;
xnorm = sqrt(sum(X.^2));
```

I think this is efficient except the two lines which assign all `NaN` values to 0. `profile` shows that these two lines cost more than 50% of all computations. Using my data matrix of size 70 by 2000, more than `10 s` is spent for running the assignments for 10,000 times. Any suggestion?

**===============**

As requested, a test function can be:

```
%%
function test
    a = randn(80,3000);
    [r,c] = size(a);
    b = randperm(r*c);
    nanix = b(1:round(numel(b)*0.3)); % randomly select 30% of values to be NaN
    a(nanix) = NaN;
    nnx = sum(~isnan(a));
    tic;
    for i = 1:1000
        t=a;
        t(nanix)=0;
        tm = sum(t)./nnx;
        t = bsxfun(@minus, t, tm);
        t(nanix) = 0;
        tnorm = sqrt(sum(t.^2));
    end
    tt = toc;
    fprintf('time: %.4f',tt);
end
```

The output is

```
>> test
time: 3.4734
```

`profile` shows that the first `t(nanix)=0;` costs 42% and second costs 16.3% of total running time.

Comment: If you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox, you can just use [`nanmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html).

Comment: @beaker tested. `6.772 s` is returned, nearly 2 times slower than mine. As `mean` function as well as `nanmean` performs lots of checks then uses `sum` to calculate mean, it is expected that the way I used is faster.

Comment: One speed up, if you have 2016b: you can mean-centre directly as `centeredA = A - mean(A,'omitnan');` instead of `bsxfun`. Also, instead of setting the `NaN` values to zero, maybe just don't include them by logical indexing: `sum(t(~ nanix))`. I can try it out soon.

Comment: @Jon `t(~ nanix)` will copy the indexed sub matrix to a new matrix, and most likely there is no copy-on-write. In my test using this method is 50% slower than the OP.

Comment: It would be good if @Jon's method can be tested. I haven't seen such discussion on performance of subindexing before.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I have included OP's way into the comparison, and crunched a couple of bugs.

---

You are looking for the norm of a vector which is the result of subtracting a vector by another special vector (constant values for elements corresponding to ~nan elements in the original vector).

Here I use the square law  (a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2, where a and b are vectors. 
This will avoid one zero assignment, as well as a singularity expansion.

Also, according to @Elkan, for a vector **a** with its mean b, sum((**a**-b)^2) = sum(**a** ^2)-2*sum(**a**)*b+n * b^2 = sum(**a** ^2)-2*n * b* b+n* b^2 = sum(**a** ^2)-n*b^2, where n is number of non-zero points for calculating the mean.

The key point of these two methods is to avoid evaluating the centered vector **a**-b which would require a second `X(nanix) = 0;`

According to Profiler, the most time-consuming lines are:

1. `X(nanix) = 0;` (~>30%)
2. `X2 = sum(X.^2);` (~10%)
3. `bsxfun` (surprisingly ~10%)

---

As mentioned by @Jon in the comments, `X(~nanix)` would pull all non-nan numbers out as the desired input. However this operation requires a memory copy which takes quite a lot of time. What is more, since the number of nan's is not consistent throughout all column vectors, it is hard to vectorize the procedure (one would have to use a for loop to treat every column, or facilitate even slower things like `cellfun`).

---

Complete test code:

```
clear;clc;close all

a = randn(80,3000);
[r,c] = size(a);
b = randperm(r*c);
nanix = b(1:round(numel(b)*0.3)); % randomly select 30% of values to be NaN
a(nanix) = NaN;
nnx = sum(~isnan(a));
clearvars -except a
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix); % count the number of non-NaN values in each column for calculating mean
    X(nanix) = 0;
    bsxminus = sum(X)./nx;
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, bsxminus);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    xnorm = sqrt(sum(X.^2));
end
toc
clearvars -except a xnorm
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    Xsum = sum(X);
    Xmean = Xsum./nx;
    X2 = sum(X.^2);
    Xmean2 = Xmean.^2.*nx;
    XXmean = Xsum.*Xmean;
    xnorm2 = sqrt( X2+Xmean2-XXmean-XXmean ); % avoid bsx
end
toc
norm(abs(xnorm-xnorm2)./xnorm) % relative error
clearvars -except a xnorm
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    Xsum = sum(X);
    X2sum = sum(X.^2); % 50% time consumed here
    xnorm3 = sqrt( X2sum - Xsum.^2./nx ); % avoid bsx
end
toc
norm(abs(xnorm-xnorm3)./xnorm) % relative error
clearvars -except a xnorm
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    nanix = isnan(X);
    X = X(~nanix);
    bsxminus = mean(X);
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, bsxminus);
    xnorm4 = sqrt(sum(X.^2));
end
toc
norm(abs(xnorm-xnorm4)./xnorm) % I can't think of a working way
```

Output:

```
Elapsed time is 6.326877 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.780087 seconds.

ans =

   8.8214e-15

Elapsed time is 3.690037 seconds.

ans =

   8.8283e-15

Elapsed time is 3.632071 seconds.

ans =

   3.0369e+03

>>
```

As can be seen, the first two methods have similar speed, while I do observe a consistent shorter time for the second one. This is because the lack of computing those things related to `mean(X)` there can be a very slight time saving.

Meanwhile, the third one cannot give the correct answer; problem is in the indexing command `X = X(~nanix);`

Comment: Well done! How about further simplified by `norm(a-b)=sqrt(sum(a.^2)-nx.*Xmean.^2`? This is due to the fact that for a vector **a** with its mean _b_, sum((**a**-b)^2) = sum(**a** ^2)-2*sum(**a**)*b+n*b^2 = sum(**a** ^2)-2*n*b*b+n*b^2 = sum(**a** ^2)-n*b^2, where n is number of non-zero points for calculating the mean. Will test tomorrow.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good test (not saying the method isn't faster), since you don't clear `X`, so there are no `NaN`s when you get to the alternative methods, maybe save `a`, and set `X` after the `clearvars`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jon Ah my bad. Will redo later.

Comment: @Yvon Thanks for you kind help. I have tested all the methods, the simplified version, i.e., using version that obtains `xnorm3` does not improve the performance. But I think if `X` is not changed during the calculations, like the versions you proposed, the codes of `X=a` and `X(nanix)=0` can be run before the `for` loop. I tried this, result shows that significant improvement is obtained, from 3.5829 to 0.8288 s. So using my MATLAB (2015a), the assignments still cost the most time, obviously more than 50%.

Comment: The `X=a` part is a bit tricky. As @Jon has pointed out I don't clear `X` in every loop, so without a fresh assignment in each iteration, `X` would contain no `NaN` except in the first loop. However, This assignment is definitely a copy-on-write. So the next assignment to `X` would trigger the memory write, and hence takes more time, which is not of our interest here. Maybe we should force  a memory write right after the `X=a` line?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what I meant, but @Yvon, you were right, it's slower than assigning `NaNs` to `0`. Also, used the TIMEIT function for better test (Elkan's answer doesn't seem right). I'm sure there are some small improvements to be made, and other approaches, but thought I'd just add this.

```
    Test Results:

func4 %# Jon potential improves on func3
  runTime: 0.00374437,
  error:5.32907e-15
func3 %# Elkan's comment on Yvon's answer
  runTime: 0.00375083,
  error:5.32907e-15
func2 %# Expanded Norm Yvon
  runTime: 0.00386379,
  error:5.32907e-15
func1 %# Original
  runTime: 0.00515395,
  error:0
func5 %# Jon's no zero-assign version of func3
  runTime: 0.00884188,
  error:5.32907e-15
func6 %# Jon's no zero-assign version of Original (norm-mean directly)
  runTime: 0.0105508,
  error:2.66454e-15
```

Code:

```
function test()

a = randn(80,3000);
[r,c] = size(a);
b = randperm(r*c);
nanix = b(1:round(numel(b)*0.3)); % randomly select 30% of values to be NaN
a(nanix) = NaN;
% nnx = sum(~isnan(a));

f = {...
        @() func1(a);   %# Original
        @() func2(a);   %# Expanded Yvon
        @() func3(a);   %# Elkan's comment
        @() func4(a);   %# Jon potential improves on 3
        @() func5(a);   %# Jon's no zero-assign Elkan's
        @() func6(a);   %# Jon's no zero-assign on Original
    };
    %Time each function/method
    timings = cellfun(@timeit, f);
    validity = cellfun(@feval, f, 'UniformOutput',false);
    err=max( abs( bsxfun(@minus,validity{1},vertcat(validity{:})) ),[],2 );
    %Display in order of speed:
    idxTime=1:size(timings,1);
    [sortedTime,sortMap]=sort(timings);
    fprintf('Test Results:\n\n');
    fprintf('func%d\r  runTime: %g,\r  error:%g\n',[idxTime(sortMap);sortedTime.';err(sortMap).'])
end

%% Functions below
function xnorm = func1(X)

    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix); % count the number of non-NaN values in each column for calculating mean
    X(nanix) = 0;
    bsxminus = sum(X)./nx;
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, bsxminus);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    xnorm = sqrt(sum(X.^2));

end
function xnorm2 = func2(X)


    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    Xsum = sum(X);
    Xmean = Xsum./nx;
    X2 = sum(X.^2);
    Xmean2 = Xmean.^2.*nx;
    XXmean = Xsum.*Xmean;
    xnorm2 = sqrt( X2+Xmean2-XXmean-XXmean ); % avoid bsx

end
function xnorm3 = func3(X)

    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    Xsum = sum(X);
    X2sum = sum(X.^2); % 50% time consumed here
    xnorm3 = sqrt( X2sum - Xsum.^2./nx ); % avoid bsx

 % relative error
end

%Try column version of setting to zero, Replace element-wise powers with multiplication, add realsqrt
function xnorm4 = func4(X)

    [r,c] = size(X);
    nanix = isnan(X);
    nx = sum(~nanix);%prob can't speedup without Mex
    Xtemp=X(:);
    Xtemp(nanix(:))=0;
    X=reshape(Xtemp,r,c); %Sometimes faster if linear?
    Xsum = sum(X);
    X2sum = sum(X.*X);
    xnorm4 = realsqrt( X2sum - (Xsum.*Xsum)./nx ); % avoid bsx

end
%Now using indexing instead of setting to zero
function xnorm5 = func5(X)

    nnanix = ~isnan(X);
    nx = sum(nnanix);
%     Xtemp=X(nnanix); %40% of time lost
    Xtemp=X(:);
    Xtemp=Xtemp(nnanix(:)); %drops by 20%, still slower than =0
    %Now have two vectors, one of values, and one of # of values per
    %original column... avoid cells!
    ind(1,numel(Xtemp)) = 0;%hack pre-allocation
    ind(cumsum(nx(end:-1:1))) = 1;
    ind = cumsum(ind(end:-1:1)); %grouping index for accumarray
    Xsum = accumarray(ind(:), Xtemp(:)); %sum each "original" columns
    X2sum = accumarray(ind(:), Xtemp(:).*Xtemp(:));%./nx(:) for mean directly

    xnorm5 = realsqrt( X2sum - (Xsum.*Xsum)./nx(:) ).'; % avoid bsx

end

%Now using indexing instead of setting to zero
function xnorm6 = func6(X)

    nnanix = ~isnan(X);
    nx = sum(nnanix); %only Mex could speed up
%     Xtemp=X(nnanix); %40% of time lost
    Xtemp=X(:);
    Xtemp=Xtemp(nnanix(:)); %drops by 20%, still slower than =0
    numNoNans=numel(Xtemp);
    %Now have two vectors, one of values, and one of # of values per
    %original column... avoid cells! It's like a "run length encoding"

    %Almost like "run-length encoding" FEX: RunLength, for MEX
    ind(1,numNoNans) = 0;%hack pre-allocation
    ind(cumsum(nx(end:-1:1))) = 1;
    ind = cumsum(ind(end:-1:1)); %// generate grouping index for accumarray
    Xmean = (accumarray(ind(:), Xtemp(:))./nx(:)).'; %means of each col
    %"Run-length decoding" %Repelem is fastest if 2015b>
    idx(1,numNoNans)=0;
    idx([1 cumsum(nx(1:end-1))+1]) = diff([0 Xmean]);
    XmeanRepeated = cumsum(idx);
    XminusMean = Xtemp(:).'-XmeanRepeated; %Each col subtracted by col mean
    XSumOfSquares = accumarray(ind(:), XminusMean.*XminusMean); %sum each "original" columns

    xnorm6 = realsqrt(XSumOfSquares).';

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised to see that the way I proposed costs such more time when impemented by @Yvon. So I do some more experiments and post as a new answer.

```
clear;clc;close all

a = randn(80,3000);
[r,c] = size(a);
b = randperm(r*c);
nanix = b(1:round(numel(b)*0.3)); % randomly select 30% of values to be NaN
a(nanix) = NaN;
% nan values
nanix = isnan(a);
% count the number of non-NaN values in each column for calculating mean
nx = sum(~nanix);
clearvars -except a nanix nx
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    X(nanix) = 0;
    bsxminus = sum(X)./nx;
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, bsxminus);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    xnorm = sqrt(sum(X.^2));
end
t = toc;
fprintf('Reference edition: time elapese: %.4f\n',t) % relative error

clearvars -except a xnorm nanix nx
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    X(nanix) = 0;
    Xsum = sum(X);
    Xmean = Xsum./nx;
    X2 = sum(X.^2);
    Xmean2 = Xmean.^2.*nx;
    XXmean = Xsum.*Xmean;
    xnorm2 = sqrt( X2+Xmean2-XXmean-XXmean ); % avoid bsx
end
t = toc;
fprintf('Yvon''s first edition: time elapsed: %.4fs, max error: %e\n',t, max(abs(xnorm-xnorm2))) % relative error

clearvars -except a xnorm nanix nx
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    X(nanix) = 0;
    Xsum = sum(X);
    X2sum = sum(X.^2); % 50% time consumed here
    xnorm3 = sqrt( X2sum - Xsum.^2./nx ); % avoid bsx
end
t = toc;
fprintf('Yvon''s second edition: time elapsed: %.4fs, max error: %e\n',t, max(abs(xnorm-xnorm3))) % relative error

clearvars -except a xnorm nanix nx
tic
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    X = X(~nanix);
    bsxminus = mean(X);
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, bsxminus);
    xnorm4 = sqrt(sum(X.^2));
end
t = toc;
fprintf('Yvon''s third edition: time elapsed: %.4fs, max error: %e\n', t, max(abs(xnorm-xnorm4)))

clearvars -except a xnorm nanix nx
tic
X = a;
X(nanix) = 0;
for i = 1:1e3
    xsum = sum(X);
    x2sum = sum(X.^2);
    xnorm5 = sqrt( x2sum - xsum.^2./nx ); % avoid bsx
end
t = toc;
fprintf('My simplified edition: time elapsed: %.4fs, max error: %e\n',t, max(abs(xnorm-xnorm5)))

clearvars -except a xnorm nanix nx
tic
nanix = find(isnan(a));
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    X(nanix) = 0;
    xsum = sum(X);
    x2sum = sum(X.^2);
    xnorm6 = sqrt( x2sum - xsum.^2./nx ); % avoid bsx
end
t = toc;
fprintf('Yvon''s edition with linear indices: time elapsed: %.4fs, max error: %e\n',t, max(abs(xnorm-xnorm6)))

clearvars -except a xnorm nanix nx
tic
nanix = find(isnan(a));
for i = 1:1e3
    X = a;
    X(nanix) = 0;
    bsxminus = sum(X)./nx;
    X = bsxfun(@minus, X, bsxminus);
    X(nanix) = 0;
    xnorm7 = sqrt(sum(X.^2));
end
t = toc;
fprintf('Reference edition with linear indices: time elapsed: %.4fs, max error: %e\n',t, max(abs(xnorm-xnorm7)))
```

The output is:

```
Reference edition: time elapese: 6.1678
Yvon's first edition: time elapsed: 3.6075s, max efrror: 4.440892e-15
Yvon's second edition: time elapsed: 3.5760s, max error: 3.552714e-15
Yvon's third edition: time elapsed: 4.0059s, max error: 4.043873e+02
My simplified edition: time elapsed: 0.8743s, max error: 3.552714e-15
Yvon's edition with linear indices: time elapsed: 2.3531s, max error: 3.552714e-15
Reference edition with linear indices: time elapsed: 3.5527s, max error: 0.000000e+00
```

Convert the logical indexing to linear indices using `find` can further significantly improve the speed. As MATLAB recommends using logical indexing to improve the performance, I wonder why this is contradictory to my results.